# Android ObjectAnimator fill after option?

Tags: java, android, animation

In my android application I am using an ObjectAnimator to translate an imageview like so:

```
ObjectAnimator transitionX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "TranslationY", 190);
```

Is there an option like fillAfter that will reset the position of the view to the new position, after the animation is complete?

Comment: This maybe will or will not work for your case, but try ObjectAnimator.pause() method.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, I'd use the property animation system instead, assuming v is a view:

```
v.animate().translationY(190).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           v.setTranslationY(v.getTranslationY()-190);
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is no option for that. However you can achieve the same effect using a listener where you can manually change it to the initial position in the onAnimationEnd(). Here is an example for scaling an imageview:

```
scaleDown.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            //Initial property values
                            tempIV.setScaleX(1f);
                            tempIV.setScaleY(1f);
                            tempIV.setAlpha(1f);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to handle this is to use an AnimationSet to merge two animations, one to translate and one to translate back the view.

Something like this

```
ObjectAnimator translateTo190= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "TranslationY", 190);
ObjectAnimator translateBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "TranslationY", 0);

AnimatorSet translate= new AnimatorSet();
translate.play(translateTo190).before(translateBack);
translate.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem like this in writing a card dealing animation where the cards are dealt quickly from a central "deck". After much trial-and-error, the way I've got this working is using the ObjectAnimator in the following way.

I add a single "deck" card at the source of the animation, and then a second card that I'm actually animating. I use the following deal_from_drawpile.xml to animate the card in two parts: the first part returns the card to the source, and the second part scales and rotates the card as it is "dealt":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
 android:ordering="sequentially">
<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
     android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:duration="10"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:duration="10"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:duration="10"
        android:valueFrom="0.75f"
        android:valueTo="0.75f"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:duration="10"
        android:valueFrom="0.75f"
        android:valueTo="0.75f"/>
</set>
<set android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="360.0f"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueFrom="0.75f"
        android:valueTo="0.5f"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueFrom="0.75f"
        android:valueTo="0.5f"/>
</set>
```

Then in code I add the actual translation which depends on how many hands are arranged in a rough semi-circle. The complete sequence of animations is then added in an AnimatorSet and fired off at the end. Code-snippet;

```
        fullScreenContent.addView(dealtCardView);
    for (int iCard=0; iCard<numCards; iCard++) {
        for (int iPlayer = 0; iPlayer < numPlayers; iPlayer++) {
            dealtCardAnimator = dealtCardAnimator.clone();
            dealtCardAnimator.setTarget(dealtCardView);
            //offsets where the cards are dealt according to player
            ObjectAnimator playerOffsetXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(dealtCardView, "TranslationX", mGame.getPlayer(iPlayer).getPlayerLayout().getTranslationX());
            ObjectAnimator playerOffsetYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(dealtCardView, "TranslationY", mGame.getPlayer(iPlayer).getPlayerLayout().getTranslationY());
            if (lastDealtCardAnimator == null) dealSet.play(dealtCardAnimator).with(playerOffsetXAnimator).with(playerOffsetYAnimator);
            else dealSet.play(dealtCardAnimator).with(playerOffsetXAnimator).with(playerOffsetYAnimator).after(lastDealtCardAnimator);
            //The card is returned to the home point with the first portion of deal_from_drawpile

            lastDealtCardAnimator = dealtCardAnimator;
        }//end for iPlayer
    }//end for numCards
    dealSet.start();
```

I can now tinker with the duration of each step in the XML to get the effect I want. Note that you have to embed the duration in each  element , not in the set section (where it is ignored, and some arbitrary default seems to be used instead).